# Слить в один два идентичных проекта в Visual Studio с небольшими отличиями в настройках

Tags: c#, проект, visual-studio

Есть два идентичных проекта в `Visual Studio (C#)` с небольшими отличиями в настройках.               
Различия такие -

- 1й проект компилируется в .NET 3.5 \  2й проект - 4.0
- Отличается несколько references именами-версиями

Возможно ли как-то слить проекты в один?                    
Может как-то через `Pre\Post-Build` события?                        
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Можно взять одни и те же исходники, и включить в 2 разных `.csproj`. Недостаток — если добавите файл в один `.csproj`, он не добавится автоматически в другой.

Comment: "Отличается несколько references именами-версиями " это опасный момент, оссобенно про версии, тк нельзя быть уверенным что все работает как вы расчитываете. Я бы не поленился и мержил вручную.

Comment: Да - пока что обхожусь линками.
Но хотелось бы упростить.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется Вам стоит уже начать себя приучать к программам контроля версий.

Мне, как быдлокодеру и руководителю проекта, нравится svn и надстройка tortoisesnv. Руководителю отдела разработки нравится git.

Раз Вы задались этим вопросом, скоро последуют другие, которые так просто уже будет не решить.

Comment: А SVN тут причем-то?
Пользуюсь конечно.

Comment: Помогает сливать проекты в один.

Comment: Это еще сложнее, чем нынешняя система с использованием линков.

Answer (score 0):

Дали хороший совет:
Копирую .csproj (оба файла .csproj в одной папке)
Настраиваю его.
Потом при добавлении новых файлов в основном проекте, просто включаю показ всех файлов (Show All Files) и Include In Project во втором.
Пока что самый простой вариант.